# androidx room multiple MATCH

Tags: android, android-room, androidx

I have a problem with androidx.room. I'm trying to use multiple MATCH in query

```
@SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH)
@Query("SELECT * FROM tests WHERE task MATCH :words OR task MATCH :words2")
Maybe<List<Test>> getByWordsInTask(String words, String words2);
```

But it works only on android 8+, on 7 it shows an exception

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) statement aborts at 7: [SELECT * FROM tests WHERE task MATCH ? OR task MATCH ?] unable to use function MATCH in the requested context
E/SQLiteQuery: exception: unable to use function MATCH in the requested context (code 1); query: SELECT * FROM tests WHERE task MATCH ? OR task MATCH ?
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATCH is special function/keyword and is not implemented other than for use in FTS(3 or 4 are supported by Room where MATCH can be used), as per

> The MATCH operator is a special syntax for the match()
> application-defined function. **The default match() function
> implementation raises an exception and is not really useful for
> anything.** But extensions can override the match() function with more
> helpful logic.

https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_like_glob_regexp_and_match_operators

You will need an alternative, perhaps the **[instr](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr)** scalar function, perhaps **LIKE**.

> I use FTS 4, all is working good when I use single MATCH, but if I use OR and 2 MATCH operators (I need it for fast, but more extended search) it works only on Android 8 and higher. I can not understand.

Try `"SELECT * FROM tests WHERE task MATCH :allwords"`

- where **allwords** is all the words separated with OR (or appropriate operators) e.g. Say **words** was ***Fred** and **words2** was ***Mary** then **allwords** would be ***Fred OR Mary***;
- if that works it might be a Room thing and if so perhaps report it as a bug

Comment: I use FTS 4, all is working good when I use single MATCH, but if I use OR and 2 MATCH operators (I need it for fast, but more extended search) it works only on Android 8 and higher. I can not understand why